# How can I secure a network faceplate without a box frame?

Tags: brick, plaster

I forgot to put capping over the network cable before the plasterers came, so now the network cable is stuck too long. There is a metal back box, but the holes on the faceplate no longer align with the screw holes in the backbox without compressing the cable beyond tolerance.

[image: stuck faceplatr]

How do I secure the faceplate? I was thinking Easifill and a wall plug. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Lesson learned - always use capping.

Comment: No - leave too much cable. You can always trim it back, you can't add it. You'll never push cable back up a cable run covered only in capping, you'd have to pull it back from the other end.

Comment: For those of us to the left of the pond, could you define "capping over the network cable" and "network cable is stuck too long", please? I presume the first means that you ended up with plaster in the hole with the cables, the second is confusing because "too long" seems contrary to the suggestions below indicating that the box is shown pulled as far away from the wall as it will go.

Comment: @FreeMan - Cable 'capping' is just a fairly thin, semi-flexible covering you roughly nail/staple/glue to the wall over a surface-mounted or routed cable. Its primary function is to make life easier for the plasterers, it's not a cable protection of any sort. It tends to get squeezed down in the process & you shouldn't rely on being able to push or even pull the cable through afterwards. Random google - https://www.electricpoint.com/marshall-tufflex-13mm-plastic-capping-cable-protection-white-2m.html With buried 'proper' trunking you can expect to be able to replace/push/pull cables afterwards.

Comment: You *can* get it in steel… but on-one ever does;) Next step up is decent trunking in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin, #TIL. Having never worked with brick/cement/plaster walls, it's not something I'm familiar with. I guess "stuck too long" means that the cables are plastered in place and the only way to move them would be to break out the plaster, possibly damaging the cable, but at a minimum calling back the plasterers to redo the work. _Not_ something most would want to do.

Comment: @FreeMan - Welcome. I think the real issue is the cables are too short, meaning you'd have to hard bend them to make them fit in the existing back box. With non-bend-sensitive cable if you come up a bit tight like this, you could just twist the faceplate 360° until it will go in… can't do that with Cat6A, so it needed enough spare to make one nice circle right to the edges of the box, then there would be sufficient flexibility to line up the patress screws easily.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hack for your situation.

Use a modified surface box or spacer to create space for the cables.

[image]

If you use one as pictured:

- **Saw a slit** in the bottom so the wires, already in place, can pass through.  After passing the wires into the extender, you can glue the slit back together but you don't have to.
- screw the extender to the back box if the screw holes line up, otherwise to the wall.  You might need to add some hardware to find a suitable backing for the screws.  Perhaps drill new holes in the back of the back box and use long screws to reach them.  Worst case, use glue or silicone but you ought to be able to rig up something better.
- Now you should have enough space for the wires.  Screw the face plate to this box.

(I just noticed, your box is near the ceiling ... so saw the slit in the *top* of the extender, the idea being it should not be visible.)

Comment: You are correct, sir! My bad. I'll just go with the original "100% agree", ignore all the rest of that babble...

Answer (score 1):

If your picture is showing the full extent of your 'spare' cable, then you actually didn't leave enough.
You won't be able to get back behind it to reconnect.
The idea is to have 6" or so that you coil up into the back box so you've got room to work.

You should have put steel back boxes in before the plasterers came, then you'd have something secure to fasten back to. If you don't have 6 - 8" of slack behind your faceplate, you won't be able to get the wires back into the sockets if you remove it, because you won't have room to get the punch-down tool in line with the connectors.

As we're only dealing with low voltage Ethernet, you could get away with a couple of skinny rawlplugs - see if you can find something the existing patress screws will bite into properly.
Worst case scenario - glue it to the wall. It'll be fine until next time you redecorate. If you use something soft like silicone or even decorator's caulk, you can cut it out again when required.

Comment: You cannot coil cat6a ethernet cable into a backbox and expect it to survive.

Comment: Cat6A needs a 4*OD radius - you can just about get that in a standard back box. If you can't reach with a punch tool, you've not got enough slack.

Comment: All helpful information in hindsight, but now these cables are stuck in plaster so I have no choice on that front. There is a metal back box, sorry it is unclear in the picture.

Comment: Then just line up the holes & tighten in the patress screws. Done.

Comment: Not possible, hence the question. Please see my question edit.

Comment: That's completely changed the issue. You're out of luck, not enough slack cable, so you're just going to have to squeeze it in the best you can. Glue the faceplate on with caulk if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on "cables are in the wall but without a junction box". If that's not the case, explain some more and we'll figure out what to do.

- Remove the faceplate from the cables
- Cut the plaster/drywall to match a standard size, using a box eliminator as a template. (If the existing hold is larger than needed, post some measurements and we'll got to Plan B.)
- Insert a [box eliminator](https://amzn.to/3B50Dzz) like:

[image: metal box eliminator]

This is the kind I prefer. There are also various plastic brackets that mount in various ways.

- Pull the cables through the hole & bracket and attach them to the faceplate.
- Screw the faceplate into the bracket.

Comment: Box shape and the indication that the cables were plastered in place suggest British/masonry construction (indeed, questioner's profile indicates a UK location) with wires "chased" in plaster, rather than plasterboard/hollow-wall...

Comment: @Ecnerwal Could be. But hard to tell from the picture - it looks like there is a hollow wall but not clear. Will need to see what OP says.

Comment: I've never seen a back box 'eliminator' like that in the UK, & google can't find anything by that name either. I feel sure they would be illegal for mains, even if completely fine for Ethernet. TBH, I just run my Ethernet through the skirting [base?] boards then wood-screw the faceplates on ;)

Comment: ahh, I *can* find them in the UK - but they're all US-shape, rectangular. No good for our OP.

Comment: Yes, I'm in England and this question is tagged with "brick" - no plasterboard (US=dry wall) here.